# EF 6 add object with existing foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework, and I have table Employee and Position. Employee has reference to Position.

```
Table("Employee")]
public partial class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public int Position_Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }

    public virtual Position Position { get; set; }
```

and

```
     [Table("Position")]
public partial class Position
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Position()
    {
        Employee = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
}
```

In Position I already have items and I get them to dropdown. All I want to do is create new record of Employee with item of Position, which Id I have from dropdown. I don't want create a new Position. I tried this:

PositionId is a property and ToEmployee() is a method in viewModel

```
public Data.Models.Employee ToEmployee()
    {
        return new Data.Models.Employee
        {
            Name = Name,
            Surname = Surname,
            Phone = Phone,
            Salary = Salary.HasValue ? Salary.Value : 0,
            Position = new Data.Models.Position { Id = PositionId } 
        };
    }
```

adding in controller:

```
var toModel = viewModel.ToEmployee();
_employeeService.Create(toModel);
```

But this create new Employee and new Position, but I want only have new Empoloyee and relationship between Employee and Position by foreing key. How to do it in EF?

When I tried this in ToEmployee():

```
Position_Id = PositionId
```

returns error InvalidColumn.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You need to tell EF that the position exists. You can do this by fetching it into tracking or by setting its entity state: `context.Entry(toModel.Position).State = EntityState.Unchanged;`. Since it appears you are using a repository you will need to adjust accordingly. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: Yes, it works, great thanks. But I wondering, how is flexible this solution? I must always know, which entity will be create and wchich entity will be only assing as FK I think code isn't look good (method in service): 


`public void Create(Data.Models.Employee employee)
        {
            dbContext.Entry(employee.Position).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
            dbContext.Employee.Add(employee);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }`

Comment: You should be able to update it via the FK as well. You may need to set the navigation to null. There are some other posts that talk about reflection if you want to go that route. There is also the [GraphDiff](https://github.com/zzzprojects/GraphDiff) library.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I will read this. Again great thanks, because it works good. But what do You mean: You should be able to update it via the FK as well?

Comment: You can directly set the FK to update the position, but you need to set the navigation property to null. See "Save the Grief and Use That Foreign Key" in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently a Position has zero or more Employees and every Employee belongs to exactly one Position. A true [one-to-many relation.](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx).

A see that you chose not to follow the [entity framework naming conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx). The one that I think causes the problem is that you didn't use the default naming for the foreign key to the Position. You used Position_Id instead of PositionId.

The following would have been standard. Because this standard follows the naming conventions there is no need for fluent API nor any attributes

```
class Position
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // a Position has zero or more Employees:
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees {get; set;}
    ...
}
class Employee
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // every Employee belongs to exactly one Position using foreign key:
    public int PositionId {get; set;}
    public virtual Position Position {get; set;}
    ... 
}
```

If you really have good reasons to use a different identifier for your foreign key you'll have to tell entity framework that which identifier holds the foreign key. This is done in DbContext.OnModelCreating

```
public override void OnModelCreating(...)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Position>()
         // a position has zero or more Employees via property Employees
         .HasMany(position => position.Employees)
         // every Employee has exactly one Position
         .WithRequired(employee => employee.Position)
         // using foreign key Position_id
         .HasForeignKey(employee => employee.Position_Id);
}
```

Now whenever you have an existing Position, with a valid PositionId, and you want to add an Employee that has this Position, you can either chose to fill the PositionId, or the Position:

```
Position existingPosition = ...;

Employee Employee1 = myDbContext.Employees.Add(new Employee()
{
    Position = existingPosition;
    ...
}
Employee Employee2 = myDbContext.Employees.Add(new Employee()
{
    PositionId = existingPosition.Id;
    ...
}
```

Both will work. Entity Framework is smart enough to use only the Position.Id in the SQL statement.

Similarly you can add a new Position and Employee in one statement:

```
Employee Employee1 = myDbContext.Employees.Add(new Employee()
{
    Position = new Position() {...}
    ...
}
```

Or add a new Position with several new Employees:

```
Position addedPosition = new Position()
{
    Employees = new List<Employee>()
    {
        new Employee() {...},
        new Employee() {...},
        new Employee() {...},
    }
    ...
}
```

There are several other deviations. They probably won't cause the problems, but if there is no reason for it, why deviate from the standards?

- The property that holds your `ICollection<Employee>` is not named in plural `Employees`.
- You let a constructor create a HashSet, which is not used in queries

A DbSet repsesents a table in your database. Are you sure this table has a HashSet? If you perform a query for a Position with its Employees and you check in the debugger the actual class of the Employee collection, you'll see that it is not a HashSet. So why create one?

Answer (score 0):

Look up the Position object in the DB and pass that to ToEmployee() method

```
    public Data.Models.Employee ToEmployee(Data.Models.Position position)
    {
        return new Data.Models.Employee
        {
            Name = Name,
            Surname = Surname,
            Phone = Phone,
            Salary = Salary.HasValue ? Salary.Value : 0,
            Position = position 
        };
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but again send a query to DB for one record is not efficent and I already have Id to add. After all, it will still create a new record if I do not tell EF the record exists

Answer (score 0):

In my case i needed to change my query tracking behavior from `NoTracking` to `TrackAll`

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt =>
        opt.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("connectionstring"))
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
        .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll)); // <- Here
```